# Parameter is not valid.when retieve image(longblob) from mysql to picturebox C#

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

```
    private void dgDataBerat_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgDataBerat.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].FormattedValue.ToString());
        MySqlConnection koneksi = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=rabanton;uid=root;password=;Allow zero Datetime=true");
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT kode_barang, volume, keterangan, berat_totalbesi, berat_barang, gambar From and_bwi_databeratbarang WHERE id = '"+id+"'", koneksi);
        koneksi.Open();
        MySqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();
        Form2 baru = new Form2();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            
            baru.lbKodeBarang.Text = rd.GetValue(0).ToString();
            baru.lbVolume.Text = rd.GetValue(1).ToString();
            baru.lbKeterangan.Text = rd.GetValue(2).ToString();
            baru.lbTotalBeratBesi.Text = rd.GetValue(3).ToString();
            baru.lbBerat.Text = rd.GetValue(4).ToString();
            byte[] img = (byte[])rd.GetValue(5);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
            baru.pbgambar.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

        }
        koneksi.Close();
        baru.Show();

    }
```

This is my code to retrieve data from MYSQL

Comment: a) I doubt you are using c# 4. b) How did the image get _into_ mysql?

Comment: are you know data type blob in mysql?

Comment: i'm using blob to store images

Comment: the problem is why i can't callback data to picturebox?

Comment: `the problem is why i can't callback data to picturebox?` I don't understand that sentence.

Comment: `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();                                  pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);                                  
byte[] img = ms.ToArray();                                                                                                          Solved, I was forgot to write this code in my input code

Comment: the problem not in retrieve data but in input data.